# Open street Map is Not Display in OSM map view

Tags: android

I have try to create application of open street map . but map is not display only grid is display. i have use a these code in my application.

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

```
private MapView mapView;
private MapController mapController;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapController = this.mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(2);

    GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(51500000, -150000);
    //Centre map near to Hyde Park Corner, London
    mapController.setCenter(gPt);
}
```

}

thanx in advance.
please.. any body tell me what is wrong in my code..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/mapview">
 </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>
</LinearLayout>

this is my xml code..

Comment: I have the same situation. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your osmdroid library into "libs" folder?
Mine is osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar

I don't see anything wrong to just show the map... :S

Comment: thanks a alot dude for reply...yes i include osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar file in application lib folder. but only grid is dispaly..

Comment: Hey @GauravPansheriya , have you found solution , i am facing same problem , please let me know if u resolved it. Appreciate!!!